# Can I use usb OTG for serial connection between nexus 7 and Arduino?

Tags: usb, usb-peripherals, usb-on-the-go

I got myself an OTG cable for Nexus 7, which works just fine. Now, I am wondering if I can connect the Nexus 7 with my Arduino for serial communication between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to this [blog post](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549). It involves Android programming, something I'm not very familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

There are reports that what you want to do is achievable. ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12822675/1609555))

I think you alteady know that peripheral devices can also be hosted on your USB port. ([more info](http://m.cnet.com/news/clever-adapter-connects-usb-accessories-to-your-android-device/57475307))

There are several apps specifically made for your arduino [in the Play Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.primavera.arduino.listener)